# angular-ui/ui-select how get the list of filtered elements

Tags: angularjs

I´m using this select https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki

as a multiple selection box

In this select we can insert a string for filter the option list so the option list start filter and reduce in order to match the string.

This is very important because we use a lot of option and is very convenient .

But how can we get the reduced list, the filtered list of option. For example, we need to create a button and wen we click we select all the filtered list so we don´t need to select every option one by one.

Is there an property in this angular select for get the filtered list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `<ui-select all-none-buttons=1></ui-select>`

Comment: Sorry, do you mean this tag contain the list of filtered elements??  How could I select it or add this list to my selection???